# How to switch between 2 audio tracks but 1 video file?

Tags: javascript, audio, audiotrack

I am a total JavaScript amateur. I want to create a section where people can switch between 2 audios with a video running along with it. I want to show a before and after version of the audio.

Basically, the video should run with the "before" version of the audio initially. Then there should be a button to switch the audio to the "after" version, and go back and forth.

I tried the "audioTracks" method, but the browser compatibility is not good with it. What is the best possible way to achieve it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You just use two HTML Audio elements and then sync their times:

```
var audio1 = new Audio()
var audio2 = new Audio()

audio1.src = 'pathToSource',
audio2.src = 'pathToSource2',

var video = document.getElementByID('myvideo');
video.muted = true; //mute video cuz we have audio already

function switchAudio(one, two, vid) {
  if(one.paused) {
    two.pause();
    one.currentTime = vid.currentTime;
    one.play
  } else {
    one.pause();
    two.currentTime = vid.currentTime;
    two.play()
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks! I tried it, the video is muted. But how do I control it with buttons? I want to add 2 buttons to the interface. One is to play/pause the video and audio. And second is to switch between 2 audios. How can I do that?

Comment: the function for switching audio is shown. for example, you could have an html button where onclick it runs that function (i.e. `<button onclick='switchAudio()'>switch</button>`). You can do the same thing with another button and a different function for playing/pausing both the audio and video.

Comment: Please look at my answer I posted. Thank you! :)

Comment: Hi David! Do you think you will be able to help me with this one? :)

Answer (score 0):

That did it :) I made some changes though. The audio seems to be working great. I could play and switch it. But the video was not starting up with the button. So I changed the code to this:

```
function switchAudio(one, two, vid) {
 if (one.paused) {
    two.pause();
    vid.play();
    one.play();
    one.currentTime = vid.currentTime;
 } else {
    vid.pause();
    one.pause();
    vid.play();
    two.play();
    two.currentTime = vid.currentTime;
 }
}
```

After this the video is playing along with the audio. But when I switch the audio, their timing does not match. The audio seems to be playing just a little bit late.